# cycle detected when navigating to a new View in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

Im trying to navigate the user to StatsView after they enter they enter in their username in the LoginView. Once they press the button the Boolean variable will set to true which should then execute the code above to navigate the user to StatsView. What is happening is that after the user presses the button the view crashes and goes to the home view which my command prompt shows the cycle detected error.

Here is my LoginView where everything is handled:

```
struct LoginView: View {
    @StateObject var data = DataModel()
    @AppStorage("login") private var login: Bool = false
    @AppStorage("username") private var username: String = ""
    @EnvironmentObject  var userAuth: UserAuth
    @State var isDisabled = false

    var body: some View {
        if login{
            StatsView(username: username, totalSolved: data.stats?.totalSolved ?? 0)
                .task {
                    await data.loadStats(name: username)
                }
        } else {
            
            NavigationView {
                VStack {
                    TextField("Username", text: $username)
                        .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                    Button("Go") {
                        self.userAuth.login()
                        login = true
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here's a visual of what's going on:

[LoginView before pressing Go](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VTVjs.png)

[After Pressing button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rQ3Cr.png)

[What should happen after pressing the Go button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJs3u.png)

Comment: Everything here would work as expected... It seems like it's an issue somewhere else in your code.

Comment: The error is only occurring here though